# How to count first letter of titles, join to tag table and print A to Z

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join 3 tables and count the tags for each first letter of the title.
I tried different ways and finally got it working but I am not sure whether it is the best way:

```
SELECT letter.letter as firstLetter, COUNT(item_tag.id) AS itemCount
        FROM letter
        left outer join item
             on left(item.title, 1) = letter.letter
        left outer join item_tag
            ON item_tag.item_id = item.id
        AND item_tag.tag_id = 1
        GROUP BY letter.letter
```

Here is the sqlfiddle link:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3155cd/2

Here is my tables:

Item:

```
+----+-----------------+
| id |      title      |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | title goes here |
+----+-----------------+
```

tag:

```
+----+----------+
| id |   name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | tag name |
+----+----------+
```

item_tag

```
+----+--------+---------+
| id | tag_id | item_id |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 |      1 |       1 |
+----+--------+---------+
```

letter:

```
+----+--------+
| id | letter |
+----+--------+
| 1  | A      |
| 2  | B      |
| .  | .      |
+----+--------+
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry I added the sqlfiddle link. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7fe6f/1

Comment: Looks good!!!!!

Comment: But the count is wrong

Comment: See previous comment

Answer (score 0):

The counts are correct.  You are counting the number of tags on a title.

According to the data in SQL Fiddle, "Hhh" has two tags, 1 and 2.  Hence, "H" has a 2 for the count.

"C" has a 1 for the count because item "3" has no tags and item "4" has 1 tag.

Although correct, your query is unnecessarily complex.  You can eliminate one `join`:

```
SELECT l.letter as first_letter, COUNT(it.id) AS tag_count
FROM letter l left outer join
     item i
     on left(i.title, 1) = l.letter left outer join
     item_tag it
     on it.item_id = i.id 
GROUP BY l.letter;
```

Also note the use of abbreviations for the tables as table aliases.  These make the query easier to follow.

Comment: I expressed myself wrongly. I am trying to count the items from the item table according to their first letter. I am not trying to count the tags. I am trying to filter the count according to the tags.

Comment: that header should be itemCount instead of tag_count

Comment: I just want to make sure you got me. The result should be without filtering: H-1, R-1, C-2, I-1.  If I filter the results by Tag 1, I should see R-1, H-1

Comment: @emre . . . If you just want to count items, remove the join to `item_tags` and adjust the `count()`.